# Grouping class object constants

Tags: java, class, enums, constants

I have a group of class object constants defined in a class like so:

```
public static class ClassConstants {
    public static final Class<ClassModel1> CLASS1 = ClassModel1.class;
    public static final Class<ClassModel2> CLASS2 = ClassModel2.class;
    public static final Class<ClassModel3> CLASS3 = ClassModel3.class;
}
```

This works, but since it is horrendously ugly and not type-safe, I would like to convert it into an enum. I can't seem to get the syntax right, though. So far, I have:

```
public enum ClassConstantsEnum {
    CLASS1(Class1.class),
    CLASS2(Class2.class),
    CLASS3(Class3.class);

    private final Class<? extends ClassModelBase> clazz;
    <T extends ClassModelBase> ClassConstantsEnum(Class<T> clazz) { this.clazz = clazz; }
    public Class<? extends ClassModelBase> get() { return this.clazz; }
}
```

While the enum class compiles, I get compile errors if I try to use something like CLASS1.get(), saying that the types are incompatible.

Since I'm dealing with a framework, Class1, Class2, and Class3 must always extend ClassModelBase, and I can't change that or modify any of those classes. I'm stuck using these class object calls everywhere, and it's already been a problem with backwards compatibility being broken, so that's why I'm trying to group the class object constants in one place.

If the best thing I can do is the static class with static constants, I'll deal with it, and if there's a better way to do this than either static constants or an enum, I would be happy to hear it. Any advice would be welcome!

Thanks!

EDIT: A demonstration of what works and what doesn't. "example" and "createList" are just for demonstration; they don't actually matter for this.

```
// Works as class constant
List<Class1> objects = example.createList("param", Class1.class);

// Works as a static constant
List<Class1> objects = example.createList("param", ClassConstants.CLASS1);

// Compile error as enum
List<Class1> objects = example.create("param", ClassConstantsEnum.CLASS1.get());
```

EDIT2: The signature of createList:

```
public <T extends ClassModelBase> List<T> createList(String param, Class <T> type);
```

Comment: This seems to be valid. Show some code where you are trying to use `get()`, for example `CLASS1.get()`

Comment: @E-Riz // Works
List<Class1> objects = example.createList("param", Class1.class);

// Works as a static constant
List<Class1> objects = example.createList("param", ClassConstants.CLASS1);

// Compile error as enum
List<Class1> objects = example.create("param", ClassConstantsEnum.CLASS1.get()); (sorry, don't know why newlines aren't being kept)

Comment: Please edit the question with the additional details. Make sure to include enough so someone can reproduce the problem with minimal effort. That means things like what `example` is and the `create()` method.

Comment: @E-Riz edited, sorry about that.

Comment: The signature of the `createList()` method matters a lot - that's most likely the source of whatever problem you're seeing. Without it, nobody can reproduce the error.

Comment: For example, this code compiles and works as expected: `Class<? extends ClassModelBase> modelClass = CLASS1.get();` So how is `createList()` different?

Comment: @E-Riz Crap, the actual method is a framework method; I'm not sure how much I'm allowed to reveal. I'll edit the question to be as close as I can.

Comment: I still can't reproduce any error. I implemented a simple method with the signature `<T extends ClassModelBase> List<T> createList(String param, Class<T> type)` and it works as expected when I call it. Using Java 16.

Comment: @E-Riz It must be a framework thing then, darn it. Probably something about the framework class represented by ClassModelBase, if I had to guess. Thanks for your help; I guess I'll just go with the static constants.